# deadlock on parallel update and delete requests

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

There is a spring boot + Hibernate + postgreSQL application in which there is some entity SomeEntity.  There is a service that works with this entity, SomeEntityService.  This service has 2 methods (both @Transactional).  The first method doSomeWorkAndUpdateSomeEntity() - does some work and then updates SomeEntity (the method takes about 1.2 seconds).  The second method - deleteSomeEntity() deletes this entity and runs in 20ms

If such a sequence of calls occurs for the same entity - first doSomeWorkAndUpdateSomeEntity(), then deleteSomeEntity() is immediately called (different controllers called these 2 methods), then in this case a deadlock is formed, since one method calls the entity update, and the other already this  the entity was deleted.  How to solve this problem with deadlock, how can transactions be tuned up?

Comment: Figure out what exact SQL statements are run in PostgreSQL, ideally by logging all statements in PostgreSQL.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: Your view of the problem may not be *complete* as you need *at least two instances* to be able to get a *deadlock*...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this will be using locking mechanism. There are many locking mechanisms available and you can read about them online when you have time.

However, your problem can be handled using LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.

In your repository class, override save method and add @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE). This will block the delete operation till save method is complete. Thus, deadlock can be avoided. Below is sample class from my code base

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, Long>{

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Category save(Category entity);
}
```

You can do similar override for delete method also.